# How do I get the selected value in treeview angularjs using ng-click directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jstree

This is my data which is assigned to **$scope.tree**:

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "vashi",
        id: "vashi",
        "children": [{
            "name": "a",
            id: "S1vashi",
            "children": [{
                "name": "bayQ",
                "id": "S1T1vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }, {
                "name": "bayQ1",
                "id": "S1T2vashi",
                "children": [{
                    "name": "a"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "b",
            id: "S1vashi",
            "children": [{
                "name": "bayQ",
                "id": "S1T1vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }, {
                "name": "bayQ1",
                "id": "S1T2vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }]
        }]
    },

    {
        "name": "andheri",
        id: "vashi",
        "children": [{
            "name": "a",
            id: "S1vashi",
            "children": [{
                "name": "bayQ",
                "id": "S1T1vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }, {
                "name": "bayQ1",
                "id": "S1T2vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "b",
            id: "S1vashi",
            "children": [{
                "name": "bayQ",
                "id": "S1T1vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }, {
                "name": "bayQ1",
                "id": "S1T2vashi",
                "children": ["a", "b", "c"]
            }]
        }]
    },
]
```

**HTML Part:**

```
    <div data-angular-treeview="false" data-tree-model="tree" data-node-id="id" data-node-label="name" data-node-children="children" data-tree-id="tree" data-ng-click="selectNode(currentNode.name)">
```

**Click Method**

```
$scope.selectNode = function(val) {console.log(val); }
```

I want to select multiple children in different cities. When I select the children it's consoling undefined.

Comment: Which is the `angular` directive you are using? What are the apis related to it? Are you using an open source directive from some project?

Comment: Using angular jsTree http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/